# Google Maps API using API key only works on HTTP referrers with www

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-api-2

After several hours looking for the error, we figured out that the Google Maps API crashes when the domain in use doesn't have `www.` and it returns the following error:

> Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized: http://domain.com/path/file.html
>   http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=OUR-KEY

This happens because since June 22nd 2016 all websites registered after June 22nd using the google maps API or any other API will not be able to use the service unless they register a valid API key.(More here: [Google API key required](https://www.multimediaxp.com/post/24/google-maps-api-requires-api-key-starting-june-22nd-2016))

**But** we already have a key and the domain is added to our list of allowed HTTP referrers on our API Credentials, on top of that we use wild cards for any sub-domain, path or request to work

```
*.domain.com/*
```

In summary after all the previous configuration using `www.domain.com` works, `domain.com` crashes.

Comment: *.domain.com doesn't match `http://domain.com` (`http://domain.com` doesn't have the "." in it)

Comment: Can you be more precise? Are you saying that \*.domain.com doesn't match http : //domain.com and http : www.  domain.com?

Comment: Yes,that is what I am saying, add a rule for `domain.com/*`.

Comment: Ok,  what is the right syntax then? Thanks

Comment: @geocodezip I see what you mean, add both wight? domain.com/* and \*.domain.com/\*

Comment: @geocodezip yes, it worked! add the answer so I can accept it. Thanks.